# Cypress visit command produces error when url is a variable

Tags: cypress

I am trying to run cy.visit() which will take a variable instead of a hardcoded value as its parameter.

In my env.json file I have an environment variable called url, which I've given a value.

```
{
  "env": {
    "url": "https://somedomain.com",
  }
}
```

In my spec file, I am trying to pass this variable when calling cy.visit(), like so:

```
cy.visit(Cypress.env('url'));
```

When running the test, I am greeted by this error

```
CypressError: `cy.visit()` must be called with a `url` or an `options` object containing a `url` as its 1st argument
```

I've searched all over internet for a solution, but it seems like I'm the only person in the world with this exact problem.

Someone knows what's wrong? Thanks!

Edit:
As **pavelsaman** said, my custom file was not loading. The reason behind this was I had *module.exports = (on, config...* defined twice in the index.js file. Maybe it will help someone in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my `env.json` file I have an environment variable called url, which I've given a value.

Cypress by default looks for `cypress.json` file, so it seems your `env.json` is not loaded.

You can check this default behaviour in the docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env.html and here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-2-cypress-env-json

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems my custom env file indeed is not loading. I am not sure why this is happening. I've created the custom file under cypress/config directory, added the url property and configured the path in index.js. 
(I originally thought the problem was in my folder structure, but I've since checked and it is now correct -  still the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

I put successfully those env varaibles in cypress.env.json, and access it like that. You probably missnamed the file or you need to the following - since it is a sub object:

```
cy.visit(Cypress.env('env').url);
```